# Validate, inform if invalid, return to loop

Tags: java, validation, input

I am having problems with this section of my code. The program asks for a couple inputs (name, ID, grade, etc.) and will then print the results back.

I decided to break away from the tutorial and have now been smacking my head on a proverbial wall  -

Pseudocode for what I want here:

```
Ask user for grade between 9 and 12
If input is less than 9 or greater than 12, return failed message and -return to loop-
If input acceptable, continue to next question.
```

Current code is as follows:

```
do {
    System.out.print("Grade (9-12): ");
    while (!keyboard.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.printf("message saying you're wrong");
        keyboard.next();
    }
    userGrade = keyboard.nextInt();
} while (userGrade >= 9 || userGrade <= 12);
```

Comment: Can you just specify what's the problem with your code ? What's not working as expected ?

Comment: Well, as it stands now, the program is just getting stuck on asking for the grade over and over. Whether I put in an invalid (< 9 or >12) or valid (9-12) response.

Comment: while (userGrade >= 9 || userGrade <= 12) -- use && condition. now every number passes (for example 5 <= 12)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with something like this:

```
boolean correct = true;
do {
    System.out.print("Grade (9-12): ");
    userGrade = keyboard.nextInt();
    if (userGrade < 9 || userGrade > 12) {
        correct = false;
        System.out.println("message saying you're wrong");
    } else {
        correct = true;
    }
} while (!correct);
```

Comment: You are not handling case when user will write `foo` instead of number.

Comment: Yes this works only for integer values. If you need additional control over possible errors don't use nextInt() .... use nextLine() and parse it.

Comment: This displays the invalid message and returns to the loop (asking again) but it still asks again even if response is within 9-12.

Comment: That would be it! Gah, I feel like I was so close but so far away. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is on the logic...

Change

```
 while (userGrade >= 9 || userGrade <= 12);
```

to:

```
while (userGrade >= 9 && userGrade <= 12);
```

The || accept anything higher and equal to 9 and below and equal to 12. The two condition make finally that any integer will be true in the condition.

Comment: actually, it should be `while ( grade < 9 || grade > 12)`, since the loop should continue until a valid number is given

Answer (score 0):

You can split your task in smaller ones. For instance create helper methods which

- will read from Scanner until it will find integer which then will be returned

  ```
  public static int getInt(Scanner scanner, String errorMessage){
      while (!scanner.hasNextInt()) {
          System.out.println(errorMessage);
          scanner.nextLine();
      }
      return scanner.nextInt();
  }
  ```
- or will check if number is in range (but that is just for readability)

  ```
  public static boolean isInRange(int x, int start, int end){
      return start <= x && x <= end;
  }
  ```

So with this methods your code can look like

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int x;

System.out.println("Please enter a number in range 9-12:");
do {
    x = getInt(scanner, "I said number. Please try again: ");
    if (!isInRange(x, 9, 12))
        System.out.println("I said number in range 9-12. Please try again: ");
} while (!isInRange(x, 9, 12));

System.out.println("your number is: " + x);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I should say that I am quite the beginner with Java. I have minimal experience but I can usually pick up on things. I'm just trying to take a simple program and expound on it and see how far (complicated) i can get.  I like your suggestion of breaking up certain tasks into separate methods!

Comment: These 'helper' methods would go inside my main() class, correct?

Comment: Yes. But since I also made them public and static you can place them in any class you want and later import that class. This way you can use them like `OtherClass.method(data)`. You can also use static import like `import static some.package.with.OtherClass.ourStaticMethod` and use it like `ourStaticMethod(data)`.